# Зависает приложение на цикле запросов requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, python-3.5

Есть приложение на PyQT5 + Python 3.5.0

Приложение по циклу делает один и тот же запрос. Если запустить без цикла - все работает и отображается результат, если с циклом- запросы шлет, но результат не отображает и окно зависает. В чем беда?

Примерный код приложения:

```
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.myfunc) 

    def myfunc(self):
        self.ui.textEdit_2.setText("")
        link=self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()
        rezultat=''
        for i in range (999):
            z = requests.get (link)
            if perem < limit2:
                r1 = requests.get('link')
                rezultat = 'Отправлен запрос'
                self.ui.textEdit_2.setText(rezultat)
                time.sleep(7)

            elif perem >= limit2:
                break

            else:
                rezultat = 'Ошибка...'
                self.ui.textEdit_2.setText(rezultat)
                time.sleep (7)
```

Comment: Дело в цикле for i in range, как правильно зациклить запросы в PyQT?

Comment: Не используйте `requests` используйте `QNetworkManager` и сигналы и слоты, это поможет избежать блокировок интерфейса.

Comment: проблема та же, что и по tkinter вопрос: [Как сделать постоянное обновление окна Tkinter? Как избежать подвисания на время ожидания ответа от сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в `time.sleep`.

Эта функция останавливает текущий поток. Поэтому при вызове внутри виджета, останавливался текущий поток – главный.

На нем работает цикл обработки событий. И когда цикл останавливался оконный менеджер операционной системы не получал сообщений, поэтому и показывал что приложение зависло.

---

Обойти это ограничение так:

```
# Ждем 3 секунды
loop = QEventLoop()
QTimer.singleShot(3000, loop.quit)
loop.exec()
```

После `loop.exec()` код дальше не пойдет и при этом поток не будет остановлен, а `QTimer.singleShot(3000, loop.quit)` обеспечит закрытие `loop` по сигналу через указанное количество времени.

Для удобства можно вытащить код в функцию:

```
def sleep_qt(ms):
    loop = QEventLoop()
    QTimer.singleShot(ms, loop.quit)
    loop.exec()

sleep_qt(3000)
```