# Как сделать постоянное обновление окна Tkinter? Как избежать подвисания на время ожидания ответа от сервера

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привет! для обновления окна использую

```
root.update()
```

Но если программа делает например запрос к серверу и долго не получает ответ- программа подвисает на время ожидания ответа. Как этого избежать и сделать так, чтобы программа была всегда активна? Спасибо!
пример кода:

```
root=tk.Tk()
def work ():
    requests.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
work()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: В отдельном потоке нужно отправлять запрос, тогда не будет подвисать.

Comment: @insolor при помощи threading? есть примеры исполнения?

Comment: Через threading или multiprocessing. Пробовал когда-то делать подобное через threading и multiprocessing, в принципе multiprocessing дает более "гладкий" результат без лагов интерфейса. Простого примера под рукой сейчас нет.

Comment: Я думаю, стоит добавить пример кода, который у вас сейчас есть, тогда можно будет на его основе показать как добавить многопоточность.

Comment: @insolor добавил

Comment: threading.Thread(target=work) так например если вынести функцию в поток?

Comment: примерно так, только ещё в основном потоке нужно будет проверять, жив ли рабочий поток, и забирать результат запроса, когда работа потока завершится.

Comment: @insolor вот тут не понял, root.mainloop() тоже надо обернуть в поток? как это выглядит?

Comment: не нужно оборачивать. В программе всегда как минимум один поток, это я и имею в виду под "основным" потоком.

Comment: @insolor все понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Никогда никогда не используйте `time.sleep(5)` внутри цикла событий -- это замораживает ваше GUI на ~5 секунд. [Используйте `root.after(5000, some_action)`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581537/23044), чтобы выполнить код через 5 секунд в Tkinter.

Чтобы выполнить работу, которая требует не фиксированное время (такую как отправка/чтение данных из сети, используя `requests.get()`), следует либо вынести в фоновый поток (`threading`), либо встроить операции ввода/вывода в сам цикл событий (`Widget.tk.createfilehandler()`). Примеры кода по ссылкам можно посмотреть: [Мультизадачность на Python: выполнить две долгие функции одновременно, не блокируя GUI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568677/23044) Конкретно, вот пример для tkinter, который читает вывод из внешней команды (`self.proc.stdout.readline()`), не блокируя цикл событий:

- вариант [с фоновым потоком](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288/e2e55eb6a2f4dccd8286b7bbb63d6917febf8676)
- вариант [без потока с createfilehandler()](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978).

Вот полный пример кода, который запускает `requests.get()` в фоновом потоке и обновляет показ текущего времени каждые 100 миллисекунд, пока запрос не завершится:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import tkinter
from datetime import datetime
from queue import Empty, Queue
from threading import Thread
import requests

def display_result(label, q):
    try:
        label['text'] = q.get(block=False)
    except Empty:  # update time at 100ms boundary
        label.after(round(100 - (1000 * time.time()) % 100),
                    display_result, label, q)
        label['text'] = str(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3])

def get_result(q):
    # blocking function
    q.put('ip=' + requests.get('https://httpbin.org/delay/3').json()['origin'])

# get result in a background thread
result_queue = Queue()
Thread(target=get_result, args=[result_queue], daemon=True).start()

# display result
root = tkinter.Tk()
label = tkinter.Label(font=(None, 100))
label.pack()
display_result(label, result_queue)

# center window
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
root.mainloop()
```

Чтобы обновить надпись (`tkinter.Label`) из другого потока, самый безопасный метод это использовать `queue.Queue`, как показано выше (то есть обращаться к `label`, только из потока с `root.mainloop()`, который её создал). Но если показывать прогресс не нужно (надпись прежняя остаётся пока блокирующий запрос не завершится), то в простых случаях можно обратиться и из другого потока напрямую:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter
from threading import Thread
import requests

def fetch(url, on_response):
    requests.get(url, hooks=dict(response=on_response))  # blocking function

def on_response(response, **unused_kwargs):
    # NOTE: it is called from another thread
    label['text'] = response.json()['origin']

# get result in a background thread
root = tkinter.Tk()
label = tkinter.Label(font=(None, 100), text='no result yet')
label.pack()
url = 'https://httpbin.org/delay/3'
Thread(target=fetch, args=[url, on_response], daemon=True).start()
root.mainloop()
```

Современная реализация tkinter модуля в CPython пытается поддерживать обращение к tkinter объектам из других потоков. К примеру, если не включены потоки в Tcl интерпретаторе, то mutex расставляются,
 чтобы только один поток имел доступ к Tcl интерпретатору одновременно.
 Если включены потоки (`tkinter.Tcl().eval('info exists ::tcl_platform(threaded)') == '1'`), то обращения к Tcl из других потоков [в очередь автоматически внутри tkinter добавляются](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c740e4fe8a9bc5815dc18c38d7f7600b128c3c51/Modules/_tkinter.c#L773-L784) и выполняются, когда управление вернётся на поток, где запущен Tcl интерпретатор ([see all the gory details](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0e950dd22b075b4809c84afda8aede02b76ac0fa/Modules/_tkinter.c#L162-L217)). [Возможны баги](https://bugs.python.org/issue11077), поэтому при возникновении любых проблем, обычно проще использовать упрощённую модель: *все обращения к GUI объектам только в GUI потоке производятся.*

Comment: спасибо за root.after, сделал уже на threading, работает отлично