# Как уйти от переполнения стека в рекурсии?

Tags: python

Допустим есть функция которая собирает данные например с википедии, функция запускает сама себя рекурсивно, лимит рекурсии 2000 по умолчанию, но этого мало для сбора данных, и мне нужно что бы функция запускалась на много больше раз, какие есть выходы ?

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

можно повысить лимит, но это приведет к переполнению стека (это такая защита в реализации CPython), и если поднять лимит выше 4000 тысяч интерпретатор не выдерживает. Собственно понятно, что я могу решить задачу и без рекрсивного запуска, но интересует можно ли что то сделать именно с рекурсией, что бы функция смогла вызывать себя раз так 100 000 ?

Comment: Увеличить стек. В моём линуксе `ulimit -s unlimited` позволил функции вызвать себя аж 4.5 миллиона раз, потом оперативка тупо кончилась)

Comment: Использовать хвостовую рекурсию, очевидно же. А, пишут, что в Python нет такой поддержки, ну тогда *sucks to be you*.

Comment: @0andriy реализовать [tco декоратор](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#tail-call-optimization) не сложно. Но в большинстве случаев следует простой явный цикл использовать (более читаемый и эффективный код). Иногда в GUI, сетевом программировании можно continuation passing style использовать ([пример динамического меню без ограничения на глубину вложенности](https://ideone.com/I3T3wq)). Чаще это реализуется с помощью цикла событий, к примеру, [widget.after в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044) (есть [аналогии в gtk, qt, gevent, twisted, asyncio](https://goo.gl/FwD17z)).

Answer (score 1):

Решено таким образом:

```
class recursion(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        while callable(result): result = result()
        return result

    def call(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return lambda: self.func(*args, **kwargs)


@recursion
def foo(num):
    print(num)
    if num > 100000:
        return 'end'
    else:
        return foo.call(num+1)

foo(1)
```

Comment: Получился велосипед для хвостовой рекурсии :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно также посмотреть на свой алгоритм и:

1. Увеличить стек, как предложили в комментариях.
2. Все же использовать нерекурсивный алгоритм.
3. Посмотреть, можно ли реализовать ваш алгоритм с применением хвостовой рекурсии и поддерживает ли оптимизацию хвостовой рекурсии интерпретатор CPython.

Comment: Из коробки - не поддерживает и не будет поддерживать, где-то даже был официальный ответ Гвидо по этому поводу.

Comment: * апнул из-за 3-го пункта. Мне кажется хвостовая рекурсия - оптимальный кандидат на решение, тем более, что у OP код свой. 
* На комментарий @insolor: из коробки - не из коробки, а найти готовое решение для поддержки хвостовой рекурсии - не проблема, к примеру, гугл знает про [вот это](https://github.com/baruchel/tco)
* и [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion) вопрос про хвостовую рекурсию в python на англ. stackoverflow