# GUI зависает во время выполнения запроса requests.get

Tags: python, gui, tkinter, requests

Здравствуй, комрад!

В наличии имеется окно `Tkinter`, в нем `Label` и `Button`. Текст `Label` каждую секунду автоматически обновляется, данные берет из сети. Проблема заключается в том, что, пока программа обращается к сайту, не получается нажать на кнопку и прочее (GUI зависает). Необходимо, чтобы кнопка нажималась в любой момент. На Python программирую недавно. Понял, что необходимо делать обновление текста `Label` в одном потоке и запрос к сайту в другом, но никак не получается это реализовать.

Объясните, пожалуйста, как это сделать **на примере кода ниже**. Желательно самое простое решение и без мусора. Буду очень признателен.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests

def test():
    root.after(1000, test)
    r = requests.get('https://time100.ru/api.php').json()
    label['text'] = r

root = Tk()

label = Label()
label.pack()

btn = Button(text="КНОПКА")
btn.pack()

test()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Связный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633670/sleep-%D0%B2-tkinter

Comment: связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экспериментальным путем пришел вот к такому решению проблемы.
Если есть замечания по коду (например, мусор), то с удовольствием выслушаю.

```
from tkinter import *
import requests
import threading

def test():
    root.after(1000, test)
    threading.Thread(target=test1).start()

def test1():
    r = requests.get('https://time100.ru/api.php').json()
    label['text'] = r

root = Tk()

label = Label()
label.pack()

btn = Button(text="КНОПКА")
btn.pack()

test()

root.mainloop()
```