# Завершение всех функций и циклов если прерван mainloop в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, циклы, tkinter

Всем привет! есть код, пример:

```
root=tk.Tk()
def do_something():
    while True:
        print('do something')
t1 = threading.Thread(target=do_something)
t1.start()
root.mainloop()
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при прерывании mainloop (человек закрыл программу на крестик) завершался цикл функции do_something? а то он остается в процессах и продолжает работать как ни в чем не бывало :)

Comment: У вас однопоточное приложение? Приведите более реалистичный пример. Тут у вас обработка событий GUI и не начинается.

Comment: это примерный код чтобы обрисовать суть вопроса, программа многопоточная, думаю суть ясна: закрываем программу на крестик- потоки работают дальше :( поправил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`daemon=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) при создании потоков  можно указать, чтобы они не переживали основной поток, который tkinter's mainloop() выполняет.

Comment: t1 = threading.Thread(target=do_something, daemon=True)- так, верно?

Comment: @babyborn добавил ссылку на документацию Thread

Comment: спасибо, работает!

Comment: @babyborn кстати, я уже использовал daemon=True в [ответе на другой ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/723192/23044). Этот ответ также упоминает, что можно root.after() вызывать вместо while True в потоке (по ссылкам посмотрите на примеры кода).

Comment: да точно, тогда я не обратил внимания на daemon=True