# Зависание GUI при выполнение функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, pyqt5, gui

Доброго всем времени суток. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать выполнение определенной функции в отдельном потоке, для того, чтобы не происходило зависание GUI. Привожу пример скрипта, в котором всего три кнопки и поле редактора однострочного текста.

Идея скрипта такова, что необходимо указать путь до определенной папки, нажав на кнопку обзора (либо прописать его вручную, в поле редактора), в которой с какой-то периодичностью появляются новые файлы. После того, как путь определен, необходимо нажать на кнопку пуска мониторинга данный папки, для того, чтобы в момент обнаружения в папке нового файла, переименовать его.

После того, как нажимаем на кнопку запуска переименования файлов происходит зависание GUI, но скрипт продолжает работать, при появлении новых файлов в выбранной папке, происходит их переименование.

Необходимо, чтобы GUI при не зависало и при нажатии на кнопку завершения переименования прекращалась работа данной функции.

Знаю, можно реализовать это через QThread, пробовал использовать его, получалось сделать так, что в скрипт должен изначально быть записан путь к папке.

Прилагаю сам скрипт, до внесения в него QThread.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
from datetime import datetime
import time

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, 
QToolTip, QMessageBox, QDesktopWidget, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

filename = 'log.txt'

class renamerus_widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn_view = QPushButton('Обзор', self)
        self.btn_view.setToolTip('Выбери папку')
        self.btn_view.clicked.connect(self.show_dialog)
        self.btn_view.resize(50, 25)
        self.btn_view.move(10, 60)

        self.btn_start = QPushButton('Запуск!', self)
        self.btn_start.setToolTip('Активация мониторинга папки и переименование файлов в ней')
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.start_rename)
        self.btn_start.resize(70, 25)
        self.btn_start.move(78, 60)

        self.btn_stop = QPushButton('Хорош..', self)
        self.btn_stop.setToolTip('Прекращение мониторинга папки и переименование файлов в ней')
        self.btn_stop.setDisabled(True)
        self.btn_stop.clicked.connect(self.stop_rename)
        self.btn_stop.resize(70, 25)
        self.btn_stop.move(150, 60)

        self.line_directory = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_directory.resize(210, 25)
        self.line_directory.move(10, 30)

        self.setFixedSize(230, 90)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Renamerus')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('путь к файлу иконки'))
        self.show()

    def center(self):
        sizeWindow = self.frameGeometry()
        locationWindow = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        sizeWindow.moveCenter(locationWindow)
        self.move(sizeWindow.topLeft())

    def close_event(self, event):
        question_exit = QMessageBox.question(self,'Закрыть','На этом все?', QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if question_exit == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def show_dialog(self):
        open_direct = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'Выбирай','C://', QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        self.line_directory.setText(open_direct)

    def start_rename(self, event):
        self.btn_start.setDisabled(True)
        self.btn_stop.setEnabled(True)
        if len(self.line_directory.text()) != 0:
            try:
                while True:
                    list_files = os.listdir(self.line_directory.text())
                    if len(list_files) != 0:
                        for i in range(len(list_files)):
                            a = list_files[i]
                            if a[2] != '.':
                                now = datetime.now()
                                now_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%d.%m.%Y %H.%M.%S")
                                try:
                                    new_name = os.rename(self.line_directory.text() + '//' + list_files[i], self.line_directory.text() + '//' + str(now_date) + a[-4:])
                                except PermissionError:
                                    time.sleep(5)
                                    new_name = os.rename(self.line_directory.text() + '//' + list_files[i], self.line_directory.text() + '//' + str(now_date) + a[-4:])
                                with open(filename, 'a') as logfile:
                                    logfile.write('Файл "' + a + '" переименован в ' + '"' + str(now_date) + a[-4:] + '"\n')
                                    time.sleep(1)
                    else:
                        time.sleep(10)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                QMessageBox.information(self, 'Папку не нашел', 'Найди то, не зная что?!', QMessageBox.Ok)
        else:
            QMessageBox.information(self, 'Папка не определена', 'Укажи папку!              ', QMessageBox.Ok)

    def stop_rename(self):
        #Тут должна быть функция, которая останавливает действие start_rename

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = renamerus_widget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как сделать постоянное обновление окна Tkinter? Как избежать подвисания на время ожидания ответа от сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044) (это о Tkinter, но похожая логика применима и для других GUI библиотек)

Comment: чтобы наблюдать за файловой системой эффективно, [можно `watchdog` использовать](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Как уже подсказали, для наблюдения за файловой системой лучше использовать специализированные инструменты. Для Qt это [QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html)
2. Поток можно инициализировать при запуске, либо общаться с ним через механизмы межпоточного взаимодействия. Как в python-е так и в Qt есть соответствующие механизмы. Например в Qt можно общатся через стандартные сигналы.