# python Tkinter не создается Toplevel в цикле

Tags: python, tkinter

есть функция кот-я работает в threading и слушает порт

```
def listenPort():
    while True:
        conn, addr = sk.accept()
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(datalen)
            if not data:
                break
            else:
                j = json.loads(data)
                if (j['type'] == "url"):
                    urls = re.findall(r'(https?://[^\s]+)', j['adress'])
                    top=Toplevel(root)//это окно не создается
                    msgtxt=u"Найдено {} ссылок. Открыть все в браузере?".format(len(urls))
                    Message(top, text=msgtxt).pack()
                    Button(top, text="YES", command=lambda:openurls(urls)).pack()
                    Button(top, text="NO", command=top.destroy).pack()

                    for u in urls:
                        lbl = Label(frame1,
                                    text=u,
                                    fg="blue",
                                    cursor="hand2")
                        lbl.pack()
                        lbl.bind("<Button-1>",lambda event,arg=j['adress']:openurl(event,arg))
                        #webbrowser.open(u, new=2, autoraise=TRUE)

                elif (j['type'] == "text"):
                    app = application.Application()
                    app.start('notepad')
                    app.notepad.edit.TypeKeys(j['text'])

        conn.close()

thread.start_new_thread(listenPort,())
root.mainloop()
```

Как открыть это popup окно? При получении сообщения главное окно виснет. Без создания Toplevel скрипт работает нормально

Comment: о tkinter и потоках: [Как сделать постоянное обновление окна Tkinter? Как избежать подвисания на время ожидания ответа от сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044)

Comment: мне непонятно почему Label ы создаются а Toplevel там же не получается

Comment: что ответ по ссылке рекомендует делать когда проблемы с tkinter и потоками возникают?