# PyQt + scapy не получается заполнить QListWidget

Tags: python-3.x, qt, wifi, pyqt, сетевое-программирование

В данный момент пытаюсь реализовать сниффер, который будет нужной мне информацией о беконах заполнять `QListWidget`.

```
import sys
from mainwindow import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from scapy.all import *


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(beacon_sniff)


def packethandler(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        if pkt.type == 0 and pkt.subtype == 8:
            rssi = -(256-ord(pkt.notdecoded[-2: -1]))
            myapp.ui.listWidget.addItem("MAC: %s SSID: %s RSSI: %s dBm" % (pkt.addr2, pkt.info, rssi))


def beacon_sniff():
    sniff(iface='mon0', prn=packethandler, count=300)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку интерфейс виснет, никак не отвечая. Если запускать сниффер отдельно от гуи из терминала, то все работает прекрасно с некоторыми изменениями.

Comment: не следует по нажатию на кнопку блокирующую функцию вызывать. Попробуйте поместить вызов sniff() в отдельный поток. Вот для [tkinter пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044) (для qt аналогично)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов `sniff` будет блокировать текущий поток, поэтому решением будет отправить его вызов в отдельный поток и для связи этого потока с GUI использовать сигнал.

[Пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/9434c2baafa64c6bd51c3d85914281ed89ed0e0d/scape__examples/sniff__gui__pyqt5/main.py):

```
from PyQt5 import Qt
from scapy.all import sniff


class SniffThread(Qt.QThread):
    about_new_data = Qt.pyqtSignal(str)

    def _packethandler(self, pkt):
        data = pkt.summary()
        print(data)

        self.about_new_data.emit(data)

    def run(self):
        sniff(filter="tcp", prn=self._packethandler)


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('Sniff with scapy')

        self.lw_packet = Qt.QListWidget()

        self.cb_log = Qt.QCheckBox('Write log')
        self.cb_log.setChecked(True)

        self.pb_clear = Qt.QPushButton('Clear')
        self.pb_clear.clicked.connect(self.lw_packet.clear)

        self.cb_autoscroll = Qt.QCheckBox('Autoscroll')

        layout = Qt.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.cb_log)
        layout.addWidget(self.cb_autoscroll)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.pb_clear)

        main_layout = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addLayout(layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.lw_packet)

        central_widget = Qt.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.thread = SniffThread()
        self.thread.about_new_data.connect(self._append_new_item)
        self.thread.start()

    def _append_new_item(self, data):
        # Если флаг не стоит
        if not self.cb_log.isChecked():
            return

        self.lw_packet.addItem(data)

        # Если нужно автоматически прокручивать список вниз
        if self.cb_autoscroll.isChecked():
            self.lw_packet.scrollToBottom()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]