# Как дать понять Windows, что программа на Python3 не зависла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyqt5, python-3.6

Пишу программу на Python3 с использованием PyQt5, когда запускаю цикл с действиями, то Windows ставит статус программе «не отвечает» и окно программы становится белым, как только цикл завершается, то графическое окно возвращается к нормальному виду и статус «не отвечает» исчезает.

Первое, что пришло в голову - вынести цикл в отдельный процесс, не знаю, поможет ли это...

Может, есть какие решения?

Comment: Нельзя блокировать цикл событий оконной программы. Не только в Python, Qt и Windows, но и вообще в любом языке, любой GUI-библиотеке и любой операционной системе. Длительные операции стоит запускать в отдельном потоке. При использовании Qt лучше в QThread,

Comment: Большое спасибо! Учту!

Comment: связанный вопрос (суть та же, но для tkinter) [Как сделать постоянное обновление окна Tkinter? Как избежать подвисания на время ожидания ответа от сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class SenderMessage(QObject):
    text_value = pyqtSignal(str)
    int_value = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        self.text_value.emit("Привет!")
        sleep(1.5)
        self.text_value.emit("Я PyQt5.")
        sleep(1.5)
        self.text_value.emit("Мы сегодня тестируем...")
        sleep(1.5)
        self.text_value.emit("Класс QThread.")
        for i in range(10, 101, 1):
            sleep(0.1)
            self.int_value.emit(i)
        self.text_value.emit("Тест завершён.")
        sleep(1.5)
        self.text_value.emit("Приложение будет закрыто.")


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        try:
            self.setWindowTitle("Многопоточность")
            self.setGeometry(400, 200, 350, 80)

            self.label = QLabel(self)
            self.label.setGeometry(0, 0, 350, 50)
            self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(25, 156, 25);\
                font: italic 18pt MS Shell Dlg 2; border: 5px solid red;")

            self.danger = "QProgressBar::chunk {background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0,stop: 0 #FF0350,stop: 0.4999 #00d920,stop: 0.5 #FF0019,stop: 1 #ff0000 );border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;border: .px solid black;}"
            self.safe = "QProgressBar::chunk {background: QLinearGradient( x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 0,stop: 0 #78d,stop: 0.4999 #46a,stop: 0.5 #45a,stop: 1 #238 );border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;border: 1px solid black;}"


            self.progress_bar = QProgressBar(self)
            self.progress_bar.setStyleSheet(self.safe)
            self.progress_bar.setValue(10)
            self.progress_bar.setGeometry(0, 50, 350, 30)

            self.thread = QThread()

            self.sender_message = SenderMessage()

            self.timer = QTimer(self)
            self.timer.timeout.connect(self.close)
            self.timer.start(17000)


            self.sender_message.moveToThread(self.thread)
            self.sender_message.text_value.connect(self.signalHandlerText)
            self.sender_message.int_value.connect(self.signalHandlerInt)

            self.thread.started.connect(self.sender_message.run)
            self.thread.start()


        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)
    def signalHandlerText(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)

    def signalHandlerInt(self, value):
        self.progress_bar.setValue(value)

        if self.progress_bar.value() < 80:
            self.progress_bar.setStyleSheet(self.safe)
        else:
            self.progress_bar.setStyleSheet(self.danger)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

На питоне не пишу, но могу подсказать 2 варианта:
 1. Запускать цикл в новом потоке (CreateThread)
 2. В теле цикла получать и транслировать оконные сообщения https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx (см. getmessage translatemessage dispatchmessage)

Comment: Информация полезна! Спасибо!

Comment: пока писал ответ - меня уже опередили, лучше конечно использовать CreateThread

Comment: Буду использовать первый. Второй вариант полезен для общего развития.

Comment: В контексте Qt стоит использовать QEventLoop::processEvents(), а не нативные функции...