# Обработка и вывод данных в PyQt5 без зависаний и статуса "программа не отвечает" Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, pyqt5, async-await

Я использовала [qasync](https://pypi.org/project/qasync/), чтобы при работе программы интерфейс PyQt5 не зависал и чтобы можно было отображать данные в процессе обработки. Всё работало хорошо, но в цикле при долгой обработке Windows ставит программе "не отвечает". По [данному вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808603/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-windows-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python3-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0) я попробовала сделать обработку в отдельном потоке, это сработало, но возникает два вопроса:

1. Я использую асинхронные функции, возможно ли асинхронно запустить поток для дальнейшего запуска функций в нём? Или это неправильно и есть другое решение.
2. Если нужно запускать множество функций в отдельном потоке, то для каждой нужно отдельно прописывать или можно описать общий шаблон, через который запускать все функции?

Возможно есть способ всё сделать с помощью асинхронности, без использования отдельный потоков. Тестируя разные варианты, я поняла, что при использовании прогресс бара данные обновляются, но в интерфейсе ничего нельзя нажать или выбрать. Также при использовании `await asyncio.sleep(0.001)` данные обновляются и при этом параллельно можно нажать/выбрать другой элемент, но я думаю это неверное решение. Я знаю, что в C# в формах есть `Application.DoEvents()`, есть ли что-то подобное в python при использовании PyQt?

Вот минимальный пример, который при нажатии "Load" загружает строки с файла test.txt и записывает их в массив с использованием `await asyncio.sleep(0.001)`, а при нажатии 'Start' считывает с файла check.txt строки для проверки, затем сравнивает данные и выводит разницу между массивами с применением progress bar.

```
import asyncio
import functools
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor
from qasync import asyncSlot, QApplication
import qasync
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys


len_value = 0
all_values = []


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button_load = QPushButton('Load', self)
        self.label_load = QLabel('Загружено', self)
        self.text_edit = QTextEdit('', self)
        self.button_start = QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.label_status = QLabel('Выполнено', self)
        self.text_result = QTextEdit('', self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        layout.addWidget(self.button_load)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_load)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)

        layout.addWidget(self.button_start)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_status)
        layout.addWidget(self.progress)
        layout.addWidget(self.text_result)

        self.button_load.clicked.connect(self.load_text)
        self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.check_text)

    @asyncSlot()
    async def load_text(self):
        global all_values, len_value
        count = 0

        f = open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        value = f.read().split('\n')
        len_value = len(value)

        for v in value:
            count += 1
            all_values.append(v)
            self.text_edit.insertPlainText(f'{v}\n')
            self.text_edit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
            self.label_load.setText(f'Загружено {str(count)}/{str(len_value)}')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.001)

    @asyncSlot()
    async def check_text(self):
        global all_values
        count = 0

        value_progress = 100 / len_value
        cur_progress_value = 0

        f = open('check.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        check_values = f.read().split('\n')

        for val in all_values:
            cur_progress_value += value_progress
            self.progress.setValue(cur_progress_value)
            if val not in check_values:
                count += 1
                self.text_result.insertPlainText(f'{val}\n')
                self.text_result.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)
                self.label_status.setText(f'Выполнено {str(count)}')

        self.progress.setValue(100)


async def main():
    def close_future(future, loop):
        loop.call_later(10, future.cancel)
        future.cancel("Close Application")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.Future()

    app = QApplication.instance()
    if hasattr(app, 'aboutToQuit'):
        getattr(app, 'aboutToQuit').connect(functools.partial(close_future, future, loop))

    win = Window()
    win.show()

    await future
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        qasync.run(main())
    except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
        sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начну с того, что `await asyncio.sleep(0.001)` является полным аналогом `Application.DoEvents()`, то есть, это способ отдать управление циклу обработки событий, в блокирующей функции. Этот способ, как будет видно ниже, используется в официальном примере из `qasync`.

Теперь собственно сам [пример](https://github.com/CabbageDevelopment/qasync/blob/master/examples/executor_example.py) с моими комментариями, который демонстрирует два возможных подхода, а именно:

1. обработка с помощью асинхронных функций
2. запуск синхронной/блокирующей функции в выделенном потоке

```
async def master():
    progress = QProgressBar()
    progress.setRange(0, 99)
    progress.show()

    # запуск асинхронной функции
    await first_50(progress)

    # запуск синхронной функции в отдельном потоке
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    with QThreadExecutor(1) as exec:
        await loop.run_in_executor(exec, functools.partial(last_50, progress), loop)

async def first_50(progress):
    for i in range(50):
        progress.setValue(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)     # тут отдаем управление, чтоб цикл 
                                     # мог обработать другие события

# эта функция выполняется в отдельном потоке
def last_50(progress, loop):
    for i in range(50, 100):
        # это заставит в основном цикле обработки событий
        # выполнить progress.setValue(i)
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(progress.setValue, i)
        time.sleep(0.1)

qasync.run(master())
```

Что касается инфраструктуры для упрощения запуска блокирующих задач в отдельных потоках, то можно сделать класс типа такого:

```
class BackgroundTaskBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    async def start(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with QThreadExecutor(1) as exec:
            await self.loop.run_in_executor(
                exec, lambda: self.run(*args, **kwargs))

    def exec_in_ui(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
        self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(method, *args, **kwargs)
```

и потом его использовать:

```
class UpdateProgressTask(BackgroundTaskBase):
    def run(self, progress):
        for i in range(50, 100):
            self.exec_in_ui(progress.setValue, i)
            time.sleep(0.1)


async def master():
    progress = QProgressBar()
    progress.setRange(0, 99)
    progress.show()

    await UpdateProgressTask().start(progress)
```

Comment: спасибо за объяснения!