# Цикл tkinter мешает работе программы

Tags: python, tkinter

Я пытаюсь написать программу с использованием клиент-серверной архитектуры. Суть программы в том, что с клиента вводится сообщение, и по нажатию кнопки оно пересылается серверу, после чего принимает от сервера ответ в зависимости от отправленного сообщения. Суть проблемы, с которой я столкнулся такова: после нажатия кнопки на сервере выдается ошибка с полученным сообщением. Как мне намекнули, проблема заключается в том, что tkinter работает в бесконечном цикле, а потому он пытается пересылать сообщение несколько раз. Но я не очень понимаю почему, поскольку функция отправки вроде вызывается только один раз по нажатию кнопки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить проблему. код клиента. прилагаю именно его, поскольку сервер тестился без него, и нареканий в работе не было, те проблема точно не в нем.

Листинг программы:

```
from tkinter import *    
from socket import *

def podkl():
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = 8000
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))


root = Tk()     
root.geometry("550x500")   
ent = Entry(root)  # поле ввода сообщения   
def otpr():   
    t = ent.get()   
    sms = bytes(t, 'utf-8')     
    s.send(sms)     
    print('Ожидание ответа...')     
    reply = s.recv(1024)     
    print('Получено сообщение: ', repr(reply.decode('utf-8')))    
    stroka = 'Вы:' + t + '\n'    
    txt.insert(stroka)    
    strokaotv = 'Скайнет:' + repr(reply.decode('utf-8')) + '\n'    
    txt.insert(strokaotv)    
def otkl(): #функция отключения от сервера, пока не работает.    
    conn.close()    
l1 = Label(root, text="Введите сообщение:")  # подпись к истории    
l2 = Label(root, text="История переписки:")  # подпись к истории сообщений    
l1.grid(row=0)    
l2.grid(row=5)    
ent.grid(row=0, column=1)    
txt = Text(root, width=25, height=15, wrap=WORD)  # текстовое подокно для истории чата    
txt.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)    
send_button = Button(root, text="Отправить сообщение", bg="blue",     fg="yellow", command=otpr)  # кнопка отправить сообщение     
send_button.grid(row=2, columnspan=1)    
connect_button = Button(root, text="Подключиться", bg="green", fg="yellow",     command=podkl)  # кнопка подключиться    
connect_button.grid(row=2, column=1)    
disconnect_button = Button(root, text="Отключиться", bg="red", fg="yellow",     command=otkl)  # кнопка отключиться    
disconnect_button.grid(row=2, column=2)    
root.mainloop()
```

Взаимодействие клиета с сервером осуществляется по в следующей форме: в клиент с оболочкой tkinter'а вводится сообщение, оно переводится в байт-код и пересылается серверу. сервер декодирует его и сравнивает сообщение с базой данных, где хранятся все варианты диалогов. он выбирает ответ на вопрос, в соответствии с веткой диалога и, переведя его в байт-код, отправляет обратно клиенту. Далее даю код рабочего сервера:

```
from socket import *     
n=1     
while n<2:    
    HOST = 'localhost'                                           
    PORT = 8000     
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)                             
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))     
    s.listen(1)     
    conn, addr = s.accept()                                              
    print ('Присоединение с ',addr)                                
    t=''     
    while True:     
        data = conn.recv(1024)     
        t = repr(data.decode('utf-8'))             
        print ('Получено сообщение: ', t)     
        if data == b'\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0':     
            reply=bytes('пока', 'utf-8')     
            conn.sendall(reply)    
            print ('Клиент ', addr, ' отключен...')     
            break    
            continue    
        else:    
            reply = bytes(input('Введите Ваше сообщение: '),'utf-8')    
            conn.sendall(reply)
```

А также рабочего клиента (рабочий клиент еще не связан с tkinter'ом):

```
from socket import *
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 8000
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect ((HOST,PORT))
while True:
    t = input('Введите Ваше сообщение: ')
    t=t.lower()
    sms = bytes(t,'utf-8')
    s.send(sms)
    print('Ожидание ответа...')
    reply = s.recv(1024)
    if reply==b'\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0':
        print('Отключено от сервера...')
        break
    else:  
        print ('Получено сообщение: ',repr(reply.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и замените изображение на текст.

Comment: Бред вам "намекнули". Цикл обработки сообщений ("бесконечный") есть в любом оконном приложении (хоть с tkinter, хоть на WinAPI). А то что у вас программа неправильно работает - это проблема с программой, а не с tkinter.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как сделать постоянное обновление окна Tkinter? Как избежать подвисания на время ожидания ответа от сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044)

Comment: @jfs добавил код рабочего клиента, и описал схему взаимодействия.

Comment: Я сам написал недавно похожую программу: https://github.com/bobreg/local_lan_chat
Я там постарался всё закоментить. Если упрощённо, то окно это один поток. Ещё один поток я запускаю с помощью threading для приёма и отправки сообщений.
Взаимодействие между потоками я организовал через after. Окна обновляются по ответам от сервера За код не ругайте, я не программист по профессии.

Answer (score 1):

Пример, где все нажатия клавиш в Entry посылаются на сервер, а ответ показывается в Label — цепочка данных следующая:

```
Entry -> queue -> (client request) -> (server response) -> Label
```

Для простоты клиента можно в отдельном потоке запустить. Запросы, получаемые из очереди (`input_queue`) посылаются как строка на сервер, ожидаемая строка с сервера в ответ пишется в `label`:

```
import socket

def echo_client(input_queue, label, host, port):
    with socket.create_connection((host, port)) as s, \
            s.makefile('r', encoding='utf-8', newline='\n') as file:
        for request in iter(input_queue.get, None):
            # send request (a single line)
            s.sendall(request.encode('utf-8') + b'\n')
            # receive response (a single line)
            label['text'] = file.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

Нажатия клавиш посылаются в очередь в `on_key()`, вызываемый через `validatecommand` параметр:

```
from tkinter import BOTH, Tk, ttk
from queue import Queue, Full

def on_key(q, value):
    try:
        q.put_nowait(value)
    except Full:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1

input_queue = Queue()
root = Tk()
vcmd = (root.register(lambda P: on_key(input_queue, P)), '%P')
entry = ttk.Entry(validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
entry.pack(fill=BOTH)
entry.focus()
label = ttk.Label(text='nothing yet')
label.pack()
```

Помимо `%P` можно и другие данные при нажатии клавиши получать: [Entry Validation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_entry.htm#M39).

Для теста, можно сервер в том же процессе запустить, перед запуском клиента и цикла событий GUI:

```
from threading import Thread

host, port = 'localhost', int.from_bytes(b'ec', 'big')
Thread(target=echo_server, args=[host, port], daemon=True).start()
Thread(target=echo_client,
       args=[input_queue, label, host, port], daemon=True).start()
root.mainloop()
```

где в качестве сервера, можно [пример из документации echo сервера взять](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import socket

def echo_server(host, port):
    s = None
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC,
                                  socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        try:
            s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        except OSError as msg:
            s = None
            continue
        try:
            s.bind(sa)
            s.listen(1)
        except OSError as msg:
            s.close()
            s = None
            continue
        break
    if s is None:
        print('could not open server socket', flush=True)
        os._exit(1)
    print('Serving on {}:{}'.format(*sa))
    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by {}:{}'.format(*addr))
            while True:  # one client at a time
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                conn.sendall(data)
```

В итоге всё что печатается в Entry тут же показывается в Label:

[image: echo via server]

Полный пример кода: [`echo-via-server.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/f5dbe136adff2e1a315031d703e370c6)

Есть и другие варианты реализации: с помощью асинхронного IO через createfilehandler(), или опрос с помощью `widget.after()` и дополнительной очереди. См. [Как сделать постоянное обновление окна Tkinter? Как избежать подвисания на время ожидания ответа от сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/23044).